# win32 setTimer start immediate

Tags: c++, winapi

if I run setTimer(hwnd, 1, 5000, NULL);

```
 case 1:
 {
 //do A...
 break;
 }
```

A part will be calling every 5 seconds.
However, I want to start A part as soon as setTimer(hwnd, 1, 1000, NULL); calls.

```
 example.

 what I want to do:
 1sec(now start looping A part every 5 seconds.)  2sec 3sec 4sec 5sec


 what really happening:
 1sec 2sec 3sec 4sec 5sec(now start looping A part every 5 seconds.)
```

is it possible to do?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: You can call the function first time explicitly or post a `WM_TIMER` message to your application.

Comment: can we able to call case 1: by function?

Comment: Calling SendMessage(myWnd, WM_TIMER, ..) will call the case:1 function, almost without delay, and synchronously.